# Passing list to viewparams variables in GeoServer SQL views?

Tags: geoserver

I have a sql view which take only one parameter, but this parameter is a list, and a need to know how can i pass this parameter in the url

Here is my sql view

```
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE id IN %list%
```

When I put the default value for %list% as (1, 2 ,3) as example, the layer preview works and show the shopa with the default ids, 
but when I try this in the url

```
viewparams=list:(1,2,3)
```

does not work.

I already tried other things like

```
viewparams=list:"1,2,3"
```

but nothing works.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: turn up the logging level and look to see what is inserted in the SQL query sent to the DB. you may need to escape the ,

Comment: did this, but in log `viewparams=null`

Comment: that will be the problem then!

Comment: maybe i need create a function in javascript to make the query to only one id per loop and join together in an overlay...

Comment: More likely to be a quoting issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution, i made the query like this
`SELECT * FROM shop WHERE id IN (%list%)`

in Validation regular expression field i put this
`^[\d,]+$`

and now i can use 
`viewparams=i:1\,2\,3`

If you are still getting 400 errors, try using the escaped character for backslash "%5C": `viewparams=i:1%5C,2%5C,3`

Answer (score 1):

Caio if you use ^[\d,]+$ , it will allow certain parameters you dont want such as 1\,\,2\,3.   Use instead the following:

```
^([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+$
```

Comment: excuse the delay of almost a year to comment. Come back to gis dev recently (same class but in master degree). Will try this now. Thanks!