# how to pass value like 100,102,103 to view params

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am trying to zoom plot numbers.Plot numbers like
1
10-12
13/P
road
20(A)
100&102
and etc.I am able to zoom to all combination plot numbers except 1,2,3.when I pass such value its trowing error:

**`1 feature types requested, but found 2 view params specified`**

geoserver sql view is:

```
select * from plotboundary where nmindar='%nmindar%' and plno='%plno%'
```

default values and validation are

```
Name  | Default Value   | validation

nmidar| Hanagawadi I A  | ^[\w\d\s]+$

plno  |  100,102&103    | ^[ A-Za-z0-9_ *@.\/#&+-\,()-_]*$
```

ajax function:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://XX.168.1.XX:8089/geoserver/XX/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=XX:vwplot&maxFeatures=5000&outputFormat=text/javascript',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: "parseResponse",
            data: {
                viewparams: "nmindar:" + nmindar + ";plno:" + plno
            }
```

Can any one tell me how to pass value to viewparams in geoserver, value includes **comma**. For example as mentioned above "100,102&103" is a single value(plot number).Here   comma is not a separator.

Comment: See another answer here that does not involve using javascript: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/128038/132832

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the Geoserver docs, I realized that we need to escape all the commas and semicolons.

The Geoserver docs for [SQL Views](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) says:

> If the values contain semicolons or commas these must be escaped with
>   a backslash (e.g. \, and \;).

We can do this using the following JavaScript code:

```
//Function to add replaceAll to Strings
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

function EscapeCommasSemiColons(input){
    var output=input.replaceAll(",", "\\,"); //replace all the commas
    output=output.replaceAll(";", "\\;"); //replace all the SemiColons
    return output;
}

//Now call the data from GeoServer

$.ajax({
        url: 'http://XX.168.1.XX:8089/geoserver/XX/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=XX:vwplot&maxFeatures=5000&outputFormat=text/javascript',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: "parseResponse",
        data: {
            viewparams: "nmindar:" + nmindar + ";plno:" + EscapeCommasSemiColons(plno)
        }});
```

Comment: for your suggestion i am getting only default values

Comment: No,its single plot number. See my updated question

Comment: its not working.I have checked my regex, for that value regex is correct

Comment: @veenahosur; I've updated the answer after reading the docs and testing the solution. Please check if this work for you.