# Allowing view parameters separated by comma in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I want to allow view parameters to my view separated by comma.

```
        My parameters are like **Z060401010014,Z060401010095,Z060401010096**

            Sql Query `**select * from plotboundarygeo where plcd in('%plcd%')**`

            And i am Using Reg Exp like 
            **^[\w\d\s,]+$**

           callback parseResponse
           maxFeatures 5000
           outputFormat text/javascript
           request  GetFeature
           service  WFS
           typeName plotgeo:vwarea
           version  1.0.0
           viewparams plcd:Z070400030091,Z070400030041
```

When i use this condition and run my application in my i am getting error like

> 1 feature types requested, but found 25 view params specified.

Can any one help how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of your SQL statement?  This might help in trying to understand what you're trying to achieve.  Also the complete viewparams argument that you're trying to use too.

Comment: I updated my question and i added my query in question.View parameters are like array of values which i mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Passing list to viewparams variables in GeoServer SQL views?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127875/how-pass-a-list-to-viewparams-variables-in-geoserver-sql-views)

Comment: I want to allow combination of number and Character like  "Z060401010095". I traid this but not working

Comment: @indu Use `ANY` instead of `IN` and in the endpoint use the escape character \ to identify the comma, or use `%5C` (depending on the case): 

`SELECT * FROM plotboundarygeo WHERE plcd ANY ('{%plcd%}')`


&viewParams=plcd:Z060401010014%5C,Z060401010095%5C,Z060401010096`